# Suppose $Y_f=D^n \cup_fY$ is the space obtained from $Y$ by attaching an n-cell via the map $f: S^{n-1} \rightarrow Y$, $n \geq 3$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose $Y_f=D^n \cup_fY$ is the space obtained from $Y$ by attaching an n-cell via the map $f: S^{n-1} \rightarrow Y$, $n \geq 3$.

I'm trying to understand the homology groups $H_{n+1}(Y_f),H_{n}(Y_f),H_{n-1}(Y_f)$ from the long exact sequence induced via mayer-vietoris sequence.

However, I am confused:

$...\rightarrow H_{n+1}(Y_f) \rightarrow H_{n}(S^{n-1})\rightarrow H_{n}(Y) \oplus H_{n}(D^n) \rightarrow H_{n}(Y_f) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(S^{n-1}) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(Y) \oplus H_{n-1}(D^n) \rightarrow H_{n}(Y_f) \rightarrow...$

Specifically on the map  $H_{n-1}(S^{n-1}) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(Y) \oplus H_{n-1}(D^n)$. The Mayer Vietoris sequence is defined here by taking the generator, $<1>$, of $H_{n-1}(S^{n-1}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ to $(1,-1)$.

My main question is this: What roll does the degree of the attaching map $f$ play in all of this? Shouldn't the degree of the attaching map show up in this homology sequence somehow? If not, why? If so, where? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'degree' of $f$? The map represents a homotopy class in $\pi_{n-1}Y$. Are you assuming $Y$ is something in particular, for instance a sphere?

Comment: Maybe you think the homotopy type of the attaching map should come up because $S^{n-1}$ is in the exact sequence? It actually shouldn't be $S^{n-1}$, but rather the image of $S^{n-1}$ (and it shouldn't be $D^n$ but rather $D^n$ with its boundary identified under the attaching map). Images of functions give almost no information about the homotopy type of the function. For example, if the degree of a map $S^n \rightarrow S^n$ is not $0$, then the image is $S^n$.

Comment: @Tyrone well the attaching map for the n-cell is a map from $S^{n-1}$ to $S^{n-1}$  and so has a degree associated with it ala how chain complexes are defined in cellular homology.

Comment: @ConnorMalin the $S^{n-1}$ I have in the sequence is the intersection of $D^n$ with $Y$, which is $S^{n-1}$. You are correct about $D^n$ should be $D^n$ with certain identifications made on the boundary. So do you think that the attaching map here shouldn't play any role in the homology groups? What you said about the images of functions gives almost no information about the homotopy type of the function was good, I needed to hear that.

Comment: Think about if I attach a disk through the constant map, the intersection will be just a point not a sphere. The attaching maps play an integral role in the homology, it is just the Mayer-Vietoris sequence doesn’t tell you it. Have you learned about cellular homology? It takes the exact approach you are looking for.

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom, the space obtained from $Y$ by attaching an n-cell along a map $f:S^{n-1}\rightarrow Y$ is exactly that:  the space obtained from $Y$ by attaching an n-cell along a map $f:S^{n-1}\rightarrow Y$. There is no map $S^{n-1}\rightarrow S^{n-1}$ here. The *attaching map* is the map $f:S^{n-1}\rightarrow Y$.